# I am trying to go back to a specific commit in Github to erase the mistake I made

Tags: github

I have looked at many past posts without a specific response. I used git reset --hard to get me to a point in time when my code was not all jacked up. Yes I should have used a branch but I didn't. Now I have a message of HEAD is now at 0600b73 fixed error. What I would like to know is how to commit those changes, so I can push them back to Git, so they are the current head? I am not even sure if VS Code even recorded the changes. Git can be confusing so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually proven you have changes, `HEAD is now at 0600b73 fixed error.`, that does not mean you have changes. That basically means that you moved the `HEAD` of git to a commit, generally you want it on a branch.

`git status` will tell you if you have things that need to be committed.

> I am not even sure if VS Code even recorded the changes

VScode has some cool features around git but it doesn't actually record changes, unless you are referring to saving files. If you save the file, well it saves.

What you probably want to do is (I am assuming you actually do have changes):

- confirm you have changes `git status`
- move to a branch `git checkout -b my-fix`
- add those changes `git add .` (adds all changes/also make sure you are at the root of the repo) or `git add -p` will let you look closely at changes and give you an interface to decide if you want to stage the change or not.
- commit the changes `git commit -m "Your message"` or you can do a longer message with `git commit -p`

At this point you can merge this branch in to master, push the branch. It's up to you.

- push your changes, `git push origin my-fix`, make a pull request and merge to master. You will then want to change to master and pull master
- merge `git checkout master` , `git merge my-fix`
- rebase `git checkout master` , `git rebase my-fix`

Here is some git learning material:

- https://learngitbranching.js.org/
- https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-git
- https://try.github.io/
- https://www.atlassian.com/git

Comment: Not really sure if there were changes made. I used git status, and  I was told Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 3 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch) Will that update my file to push the old changes?

Comment: All I am looking to do is revert back to a working site.

Comment: Keep getting no changes after I try to add .

Comment: This means that your HEAD/branch has 3 less commits than what you have on `origin/master`, in other words it is behind.`Will that update my file to push the old changes`  No it will not. I recommend you go through those steps, they are pretty safe until you get to the merging portion. At that point I recommend you use the first option I mention and do a pull request in github. There is a tab in pull requests that will show you your changes.